# Topshelf install command not returns

Tags: topshelf

I am using Topshelf v3.1 to install my console app as a windows service. I install my console via command line like: myconsole install

Everything seems good except that the command seems never complete, I mean usually once a command is executed, the command line console will be back the state that you can type another command again. Somehow topshelf command stops at the last point so I have to Control + C to kill the command.

My code is below:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //HostFactory.Run(x =>
            //{
            //    x.Service<DummyService>(s =>
            //    {
            //        s.ConstructUsing(name => new DummyService());
            //        s.WhenStarted(tc => { });
            //        s.WhenStopped(tc => { });
            //    });

            //    x.RunAsLocalSystem();
            //    x.SetDescription("DummyService1");
            //    x.SetDisplayName("DummyService2");
            //    x.SetServiceName("DummyService3");
            //    x.StartAutomatically();
            //});
            var service = new DummyService();
            service.Run();            
        }
}
```

Somehow, if I uncomment out the block that I commented out above and comment out the last 2 lines in the Main method. Then I run the command again, it magically works.

PS: DummyService.Run method just wraps the commented code block. Essentially, they are the same.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Ld

Answer (score 1):

Topshelf is for running services. This is the expected behaviour. The service needs to run continuously (until a stop command is sent) as Windows Services normally act. At the command line you need to CTRL+C to signal the end of the service.

If you want to run just a command, Topshelf is the wrong way to do it. Topshelf allows you to run the service normally as a command line as an easy way to debug services.